# node js parsing emails and content

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, email

Hey all currently attempting to implement a program in node.js which receives the body of an email (already implemented) and then using the format of the email; which is static, builds some kind of object containing the relevant data.

An example email would be in a template like so:

```
name: "name"

email: "email"
```

emails sent with outlook are formatted with HTML however and come through like so

input:

```
"<html>\r\n<head>\r\n<meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=utf-8\">\r\n<meta content=\"text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\">\r\n<style type=\"text/css\" style=\"display:none\">\r\n<!--\r\np\r\n\t{margin-top:0;\r\n\tmargin-bottom:0}\r\n-->\r\n</style>\r\n</head>\r\n<body dir=\"ltr\">\r\n<div id=\"divtagdefaultwrapper\" dir=\"ltr\" style=\"font-size:12pt; color:#000000; font-family:Calibri,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif\">\r\n<p>test<br>\r\n</p>\r\n</div>\r\n</body>\r\n</html>\r\n"
```

and some kind of output like JSON storing these two values.

so far I've tried trimming all the HTML and removing the \r\n which is fine for just getting the content but I'm not sure how I'd take the values for name and email and store it as JSON

```
{
"form":
    {"name":"John", "email":"example@example.com"},
}
```

Comment: If it's HTML, why not use something like Cheerio to parse as such?

Comment: you might want to google for a rfc822 or rfc2822 parser in JavaScript that converts to JSON for you.

Comment: @Paul, just a follow up question now that I've got my solution mostly working: sometimes each line in my email body is a <div> element, other times its a <p> element. This is seemingly random as roughly half use divs and half use p tags is this normal?

Comment: Your sample html content doesn't include a name or email at all.  Where would you expect to extract them from?